# How to UPDATE a column of all duplicate records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For e.g., I have a MySQL table named "Qbank" which has following columns

- ID (int AUTO_INCREMENT)
- Question (longtext)
- Repeated (int, default 0)

I know how to get counts of repeated rows (Questions) -

```
SELECT Question,
       Repeated,
       count(ID) as cnt
FROM Qbank
GROUP BY Question
HAVING cnt > 1
```

And also, to get a list of all duplicate rows -

```
SELECT ID, Qbank.Question, Repeated FROM Qbank 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Question
    FROM Qbank 
    GROUP BY Question
    HAVING count(ID) > 1
) dup ON Qbank.Question = dup.Question 
ORDER BY Question
```

**But what I want to do is - to SET the "Repeated" value of all the duplicates (having same Question) to 1.**
I.e. so that these can be differentiated from remaining non-duplicate questions, which have Repeated value 0 by default.

#### What would be the structure of such query?

Sorry, for the elaboration, that was the only way to prove, that I have searched a lot before asking, and have not found anything yet.

Thanks.

Regards,
Dr. Atul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` in `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Qbank T1 JOIN 
  (SELECT Question FROM Qbank 
   GROUP BY Question HAVING count(ID) > 1) dup ON T1.Question = dup.Question 
SET T1.Repeated = 1
```

Comment: Very useful solution indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Update duplicates using `GROUP BY`:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE wlvalidation wvl
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT w.`id`,w.`active`,w.`isused` ,w.wl_key,COUNT(w.`wl_key`) AS ked FROM   wlvalidation w WHERE w.`isused`=0 AND w.`wl_company`='afr'
GROUP BY w.`wl_key`
HAVING COUNT(w.`wl_key`) > 1)drs
ON wvl.`id`=drs.`id`
SET wvl.`active`=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set 1 to all repeated questions by unsing `sub-query`:

```
UPDATE Qbank 
    SET Repeated = 1
WHERE Question IN (SELECT Question FROM Qbank 
   GROUP BY Question HAVING count(ID) > 1)
```